# Stop or Pause a Marquee in Starting Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I have Some Queries Related to Marquee in HTML
1.First i have created a Simply Marquee that movies in Direction Upwards
2.Marquee Contents are Entered in List.
3.Every List should stop for 1 Sec in Staring Position

Is there any way to Solve This Issues

Here is the Picture For Your clarification 
 [image]

Comment: Can you post your code here

Comment: Please clarify what is working and what is not. Could you post code what already works (jsfiddle) and what should change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xMCv/ this is the link.. i just need to stop the marquee in starting position for some time..

Comment: @dreamweiver the link is just marquee ..  
jsfiddle.net/4xMCv .. i just need JS to Stop in Starting Position.

Comment: First throw the marquee away and put a `transition` in the CSS for the list. Then, using JS, set the top margin to a smaller value than its current value. Wait until the transition has ended. Repeat.

Comment: @MrLister can u put the code here.. or any examples.

Comment: What is the HTML you have so far?

Comment: @MrLister i just created a simple marquee in list and need to scroll in up direction and need to stop in starting position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with div as marquee is not cross-browser.

i have also added `<div id="cont"></div>` to show that even if has something on top it will still work.

code for stooping Every List should stop for 1 Sec in Staring Position

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4yYsu/2/

## **html**

```
<div id="cont"></div>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="mytext">
        <li>this is a simple text to test custom marquee</li>
        <li>this is a simple text</li>
        <li>test custom marquee</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## **css**

```
#cont {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    position:absolute;
}
#mytext {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

## **js**

```
txt = $("#mytext");
length = $("#mytext li").length;
height_ul = parseInt(txt.height());
height_li = parseInt(txt.height()) / length;
delta = 0;
run();

function run() {
    delta = (delta - height_li < -1 * height_ul) ? height_ul : delta - height_li;
    if (delta <= 0) {
        scroll_li(delta);
    } else if (delta = height_ul) {
        txt.animate({
            top: delta
        }, 0, "linear");
        delta = 0;
        scroll_li(delta);
    }
    setTimeout(run, 1000);
}

function scroll_li(delta) {
    txt.animate({
        top: delta
    }, 2000, "linear").delay(1000);
}
```

previous code

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4yYsu/

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont"></div>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="mytext">
        <li>this is a simple text to test custom marquee</li>
        <li>this is a simple text</li>
        <li>test custom marquee</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cont {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    position:absolute;
}
#mytext {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**js**

```
$(function () {
    var txt = $("#mytext");
    txt.bind('scroll', function () {
        var el = $(this);
        // Scroll state machine
        var scrollState = el.data("scrollState") || 0;
        el.data("scrollState", (scrollState + 1) % 4);
        switch (scrollState) {
            case 0:
                // initial wait
                el.css({
                    top: 0
                });
                el.show();
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    el.trigger("scroll");
                }, 1000);
                break;
            case 1:
                // start scroll
                var delta = 0 - parseInt(el.height());
                if (delta < 0) {
                    el.animate({
                        top: delta
                    }, 2000, "linear", function () {
                        el.trigger("scroll");
                    });
                    delta = -1 * parseInt(delta) + 'px';
                    el.animate({
                        top: delta
                    }, 0, "linear", function () {
                        el.trigger("scroll");
                    });
                    el.animate({
                        top: 0
                    }, 2000, "linear", function () {
                        el.trigger("scroll");
                    });
                }
                break;
        }
    }).trigger("scroll");
});
```

Comment: "marquee is not cross-browser"? What browser are you using? Other than that, your solution is fine and dandy, but I don't think it's what the OP wants. "Every LI should stop here for 1 Sec..."

Comment: I am doing This for displaying news and every news should be moving in upwards direction and need to pause in a specific location for 1 ~ 2 sec and again it should resume and next news should follow same thing.. @MrLister

Comment: Oh... that's not what you said first. I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4xMCv/2/), that does stop at every list item before continuing, but apparently that is not what you need either.

Comment: check this out buddy <http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee>  The `<marquee>` element is a non-standard element.

Comment: @TusharGupta You haven't disproved my point, nor answered my question.

Comment: @MrLister I use latest browsers but the fact is that older browser don't support marquee and The <marquee> element is a non-standard element.

Comment: @MrLister this code works fine on JFiddle but when i inserted this piece in my code its not working..

Comment: The Site is developed in local host .. just copied the whole code and pasted it in appropriate place.. @MrLister

Comment: yup this also shows only the list items but its not scrolling ? i have test in chrome and firefox too @TusharGupta

Comment: did this fiddle work for you ? have you included jquery files ?

Comment: @TusharGupta in fiddle its running when i copy the code and paste it in my site means not working.. s s i have included this jquery-1.8.3 in that..

Comment: is there any external java script file should be added means please mention here or link it .. @TusharGupta

Comment: bro.. thanks thanks i forgot to insert this code in my site `window.onload=function()` any way both of yours code works awesome thanks again @TusharGupta

Comment: bro.. thanks thanks i forgot to insert this code in my site window.onload=function() @MrLister

Comment: hi @MrLister i have another issue in this i just need to stop that LI on mouse over .. but when i inserted the `onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"` code its not working.. any problem in this...

Comment: hi @TusharGupta i have another issue in this i just need to stop that LI on mouse over .. but when i inserted the `onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"` code its not working.. any problem in this...

Comment: @coolprarun What he said. Make this a new question and show your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following link

https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee

Its a simple plugin for jQuery. What you are looking for can be done modifying the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The Exact Correct Answer For This solution is Given By **Mr Lister** see the comments to Get solution 
The Solution for this Question is below..

Here is the Working Code..

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
      <li> this is a simple text to test custom marquee</li>
      <li> this is a simple text </li>
      <li> test custom marquee </li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var top = 8; run();

function run()
{
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    var time = 2000;
    if (top<-4) {
        top = 8; 
        ul.style.transition = 'none';
        time = 100;
    }
    else if (top>0) {
        top = 0; 
        ul.style.transition = 'all 4s linear';
        time = 5000;
    }
    else {
        top -= 2;
        ul.style.transition = 'all 1s linear';
    }
    ul.style.marginTop = ''+top+'em';
    setTimeout(run, time);
}
```

**CSS :**

```
.container {height:8em; overflow:hidden}
ul {margin-top:8em;}
li {white-space:nowrap; line-height:2; margin-top:0;}
```

Mr Lister
Thanks So Much for quick reply and this is what i exactly need .. Thanks Again